# use visual studio code coverage as external tool

Tags: visual-studio, code-coverage

I would like to leverage visual studio code coverage ability out side Visual Studio as diagnostic test on environment without a Visual Studio instance on it.

I could not grab a tutorial or guideline on how it is done.
So how it can be done?
Even guidelines are good.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version?

Comment: Currently using 2012, shortly move to 2013.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2012 or newer you can use the `vstest.console.exe` to invoke tests to gather code coverage. the [`/enableCodeCoverage` commandline switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx) enables it.

You can gather coverage from a commandline using the older `vsperfcmd` tool as well. This requires you to have at least a Visual Studio Test Agent installed on the machine. This is no full Visual Studio installation, but it contains teh components required to run tests and gather coverage details.

[How to setup the `VsPerfCmd` tool can be found here in this MSDN post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9b299ba-2d82-4f75-8563-8c3f9fb9e628/using-vsperfcmd-for-code-coverage?forum=vststest). I copied the steps:

I assume you want code coverage on MyApp.exe

1. Open Visual studio command prompt
2. Add `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Team Tools\Performance Tools` to the path

   `set path=%path%;'%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10\Team Tools\Performance Tools'`
3. CD to the folder that contains MyApp.exe
4. Instrument MyApp.exe for coverage:

   `vsinstr -coverage MyApp.exe`
5. Start the coverage monitor to collect code coverage data:

   `vsperfcmd -start:coverage -output:MyApp.coverage`
6. Run the instrumented MyApp.exe:

   `MyApp.exe`
7. Shut down the monitor once MyApp.exe is done:

   `vsperfcmd -shutdown`
8. Open the MyApp.coverage file in Visual Studio

With the [Test Agent installed on the machine, you can also trigger a test run from Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182534.aspx) (even if it is installed on a different machine).